# How to eliminate duplicates in a SQL table with the following values?

Tags: sql, duplicates

```
S_No.    Name        HRA
1        SS          123
2        SS          123
3        SS          123
4        SS          124
5        SA          222
6        SA          222
7        SA          221
8        SE          222
9        SE          123
10       SE          123
```

Desired Result

```
S_No.    Name        HRA
1        SS          123
4        SS          124
5        SA          222
7        SA          221
8        SE          222
9        SE          123
```

Comment: Do you want the duplicates filtered or actually removed, ie `DELETE FROM...`?

Comment: Just filtered. Thank you for editing my input! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
select min(s_no), name, hra
from table_name
group by name, hra
```